# php round number - When echo it displays 2 decimals, if print to CSV it displays .0999999

Tags: php, floating-point, rounding, precision, number-formatting

Using http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/ to export to CSV and Excel.

I have a `$rows` array wich contains all rows with it's columns.

Some columns have a formatted number using `number_format(round((float)$number, 2 ), 2, '.', '');` This `$number` is a column from a query result.

If I var_dump `$rows` every number is well formatted.

When I do

```
 Excel::create($filename, function($excel) use ($rows) {
    $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function($sheet) use ($rows) {
        $sheet->rows($rows);
    });
})->export('csv');
```

it exports to CSV (same happens if I choose excel) and some columns display numbers wrongly like `82.70999999999999` instead of `82.71`

Can't find a way to fix this

Comment: how did you print it to CSV?

Comment: Show us the relevant code.. What is `$number` and where are you building the CSV? Also how are you accessing the CSV after?

Comment: Share more code how you put value to csv?

Comment: let me guess `$number` is . no wait how about you just tell us?

Comment: I have tried doing this and it is putting the data correctly into the CSV.

`<?php

$number = 87.6546546546546546546;

$number = number_format(round((float)$number, 2 ), 2, '.', '');

echo $number;

$handle = fopen("test.csv", "w");

fputcsv($handle, array($number));

fclose($handle);

?>`

Is this the same thing you are doing?

Comment: can you share more about your code? I don't know what are you assigning to `$number`

Comment: Ahhm don't use CSV, use [SYLK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYmbolic_LinK_(SYLK)).

That will give you much more control over formatting, and Excel won't try to guess the type of a field by examining the contents. 

But if you need to use CSV try to convert it as a String first, then do the export.

Comment: I tried doing `(string)number_format(round((float)$number, 2 ), 2, '.', '');`. It still displays the same. Also `number_format` already returns a string.

Comment: even if I don't use `number_format(round((float)$number, 2 ), 2, '.', '');` it displays the same. But If I do `$number = $number . '-test'` it will display everything okay with '-test' after.

Answer (score 0):

when you format the column try this straight forward solution:

`$number = 82.70999999999999;
$float_string = sprintf("%.2f", $number); // $float_string = "82.71";`

That will replace your `number_format(round((float)$number, 2 ), 2, '.', '');`

Hope it helps~!